# C++11 init templated member variable

Tags: templates, c++11

I want to have templated member variable, inited with constructor, like this:

```
struct S{
    //typedef S ThisT;

    template<class IdsT, class DataT>
    struct CallbackPack{
        /*constexpr */CallbackPack(IdsT &selfIds):
            selfIds(selfIds){}

        const IdsT  &selfIds;
    };    

    const  CallbackPack<S, S> callbackPack123 = CallbackPack<S, S>((*this));
};
```

But when I try to compile this I get error.

```
g++-4.8 -std=c++11 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out
main.cpp:16:65: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration
     const  CallbackPack<S, S> callbackPack123 = CallbackPack<S, S>((*this));
                                                                 ^
main.cpp:16:66: error: expected unqualified-id before '>' token
     const  CallbackPack<S, S> callbackPack123 = CallbackPack<S, S>((*this));
                                                                  ^
main.cpp:16:65: warning: non-static const member 'const S::CallbackPack<S, S> S::S' in class without a constructor [-Wuninitialized]
     const  CallbackPack<S, S> callbackPack123 = CallbackPack<S, S>((*this));
                                                                 ^
main.cpp:16:62: error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 2)
     const  CallbackPack<S, S> callbackPack123 = CallbackPack<S, S>((*this));
                                                              ^
main.cpp:9:12: error: provided for 'template<class IdsT, class DataT> struct S::CallbackPack'
     struct CallbackPack{
            ^
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ea9ed4482306ce17

Comment: `'const S::CallbackPack<S, S> S::ThisT' conflicts with previous declaration
main.cpp:6:15:  'typedef struct S S::ThisT'`

Comment: Nope - http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dc5d74705c410e12

Comment: Read your errors and fix them!  `main.cpp:16:65: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration`

Comment: @RobertHarvey: It's not super obvious how to fix that one, check it again.  The error is significantly more subtle I think.  It has to do with _exactly_ when a type is considered fully defined vs partially defined and what templates you can instantiate with it when.  I think

Comment: I have fixed, all that I see. And update question. Sorry, but I really not see an error.

Comment: funny though, it compiles with clang++ but spits an error in g++.

Comment: Oh, it seems I'm very lucky with gcc...

Comment: it's unlucky because usually it's clang that struggles with funny templates.

Comment: So, you people think this rather compiler bug, than mine? :)

Comment: Workaround: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3e0c71de722801bb

Comment: @dyp - Nice, what that braces {} mean, and why it work? :)

Comment: That's C++11's "uniform initialization", actually called *list-initialization* in the C++ Standard. The `{..}` is called a *braced-init-list*. Why does it work? I suspect there's a bug in g++ that has to do with the `<..>` in a non-static data member initializer.

Comment: @dyp: I think that comment invalidates my hard worked answer.

Comment: This does look like a compiler bug.  I found several variations that g++ has no problem with.

Comment: Dyp found these bug reports: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51666 https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52595

Comment: Ok, I try to reopen/submit bug now.

Comment: Well, I have posted a bug https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61290 ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mooing Duck said, this is compiler bug https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52595.

To avoid it, you should add parentheses:

```
const  CallbackPack<S, S> callbackPack123 = (CallbackPack<S, S>(*this));
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

If I'm understanding what you want right, try out this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <functional>

struct S{
    S() : callbackPack123(*this) {}

    template<class IdsT, class DataT>
    struct CallbackPack{
        // Initializing reference with nullptr is NOT A GOOD THING.
        // I'm just doing it to prove that no default constructors are called.
        CallbackPack() : selfIds_(nullptr) {
            std::cout << "EMPTY CONSTRUCTOR CALLED\n";
        }
        CallbackPack(IdsT &selfIds) : selfIds_(selfIds) {
            std::cout << "IdsT CONSTRUCTOR CALLED\n";
        }

        const IdsT  &selfIds_;
    };    

    const  CallbackPack<S, S> callbackPack123;
};

int main()
{
    S s;
    return 0;
}
```

It prints

```
IdsT CONSTRUCTOR CALLED
```

and nothing else, indicating that the member has been created with the IdsT constructor. I hope this answers your question.

Comment: I know. The question was, how to do the same, but with parameterized constructor. That's "member variable, inited with constructor" - in my question :)

Comment: @tower120 I'm not sure I understand. The member variable is initialized within a constructor. What is that you want to do that is not applicable here?

Comment: I want to init callbackPack123 variable with (*this). Want CallbackPack(IdsT &selfIds) to be called, not default empty constructor.

Comment: @tower120 It does not work like this. Since the member is initialized within the constructor initializer list, it never calls any default empty constructor. What you want is what it happening. Try it out.

Comment: That should not compile. You can't initialize a reference from a `std::nullptr_t`. Edit: Oh wait, I think it's UB, NDR because that ctor is never instantiated.

Comment: Let's try from another side. I want this http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3a26d71a7046dc49 , but I need it with templates.

Comment: @tower120: How is that any different from the two answers here?  Our answers do the exact same thing.  _Why_ do you want that?

Comment: @MooingDuck maybe, you mean not me?

Comment: @dyp: It's not UB, you can totally have somewhat invalid code in non-instantiated functions, most template classes rely on it.

Comment: @MooingDuck Oh... wait you're right, `IdsT` could be constructible from `nullptr`, so this could create a temporary and bind it to `selfIds_`. Not a good idea, but definitely no UB. I thought this falls under the rule in [temp.res]/8 "If no valid.."

Comment: @dyp Yeah, just deleted the comment because I found out myself. Well, at least I learned something new! (Although I don't think it's going to be useful.. ever)